# Where can I find a Shimano cs50 stopper fixing bolt?

Tags: repair, parts, shimano, cable

Somehow I lost a single 'stopper fixing bolt' on my down tube cable stop. I have a set of Shimano sm-cs50 outer down tube cable stops, and I don't want to buy new ones because I only need one bolt. Does anyone know the exact name of the bolt, or where I might find a substitute for it?

[image: shimano cs50 downtube cable stop]

Comment: Presumably you have the other bolt. Take it to your local hardware shop (e.g. Home Depot) and look in the hardware section for a new bolt. I'd guess its a M5 bolt, but you can easily match its length and size by looking through the nuts, screws and bolts of the hardware shop. Worst case, you get a whole new set of stops for 10 bucks or whatever, online. They should have hex headed ones, but sometimes you'll have to do with a philips/flat head one.

Comment: If you already have a good relationship with your LBS they might just give you one, or charge a nominal fee.

Comment: A well-equipped hardware store (probably not Home Depot) should have a selection of stainless steel metric bolts.  Or a bike shop can probably help you.  (The bolt likely does not have to be a round-head -- a "socket-head cap screws" would probably work as well -- but you may find a "socket-head button screws" if you look around.)  See http://store.curiousinventor.com/media/images/guides/metal_working/screws/machine_screws3.jpg?1248413326

Comment: I think it depends on your home depot (our Lowes is significantly worse stocked than our home depot), but I'm pretty sure I saw appropriate bolts for this while I was picking up some M3-.5x6mm screws at my local home depot today to repair my belt.

Comment: http://www.mcmaster.com/ They have a huge selection of small hardware.  Measure your existing bolt and get a replacement of similar length. These folks ship very quickly, so you should have your item in a couple days.  I've ordered lots of different metric bolts for mounting racks, fenders, bottles, etc...

Answer (score 4):

Those are **M5 button head cap screws** (the entire name is needed to specific the exact part), usually 8mm or 10mm long. You can buy them from any fastener supplier, and many hardware shops as well as bike shops.